# Mysql configuration error in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, database-connection

Using this configuration in `wp-config.php` to connect to mysql:

```
define('DB_NAME','office_corp');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','password');
define('DB_HOST','localhost');
```

I am getting the error message:

> Error establishing a database connection

But when I use the same credentials to log in to mysql in localhost, I can log in and can see `office_corp` among other databases. I updated my mysql today to 5.6 but I do not see any issue with that.

Comment: How you login successfully to mysql? with phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Yes. Through both phpMyAdmin and also using command mysql -uroot-p

Comment: try – in same wp site root – to establishing a db connection using pdo or mysqli to test if the problem is wp-related

Comment: The problem is not related to wp as other databases in server can be accessed

Comment: but if you try your own connection, you can retrieve (maybe) more info about error. When you say “as other databases in server can be accessed” you intend accessed by **same** wp root/config file?

Comment: I have written 3 different config files which are being accessed by wp-config depending on the environment type

Comment: I suggest you to try a classic php connection to see if there are error.

Comment: check this [link] http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-error-establishing-a-database-connection-in-wordpress/

Comment: What is your previous version of mysql? and how you have update the wp db?

Comment: I had 5.5, now I updated it to 5.6

Comment: I have to go, I'm sorry. If `mysqli_connect( DB_HOSTS, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME ) or die(mysqli_connect_error())` doesn't output error, the problem is wp. backup your db and follow your tutorial (or, better, take a look at wp official support site). I'll be back in 8 hours.

Comment: For security reasons, do not use `root` as user for WP or any website for that matter.

Comment: I am using other password for the development product. This is just for my local db for testing before I deploy the changes on the dev and prod db.